# Extract A Year From DateTime, Update Column In Same Record

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

I have a table similar to the below

```
Date                    |       Year
2015-03-01 00:00:00:00          NULL
2014-01-02 00:00:00:00          NULL
```

I am trying to write a statement that would extract the year from the DateTime column **Date**, and place it in the nvarchar(4) column of **Year.**

The expected result would be:

```
Date                    |       Year
2015-03-01 00:00:00:00          2015
2014-01-02 00:00:00:00          2014
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
update table
set [year] = year([Date])
```

SQL Server has a Year function which returns the year (as an int) of the date you apply it to.

Answer (score 0):

You cna make use of the `DATEPART` function here to extract the `Year`.

```
update table set year = DATEPART(Year, Date)
```